Film in which a kid communicates with / meets her depression era grandpa in the past?
I'm trying to find the name of a movie in which a kid from the present (80s or 90s) either communicates with or travels back in to time to meet her grandfather in the past. 
This was a movie I saw when I was a kid, so it would have been released in the 80s or 90s.  It's possible it was from the 70s and I just saw it in my childhood, but what I remember of it suggests 80s or 90s.  It was a live action film.
I don't remember much about the movie except the ending scene. 
The kid's family is very poor and she's struggled with that.  The family is poor, in part, due to her grandfather's choices during the great depression.  I think maybe they're living on a farm and they risk losing the farm in the present day?  
In any case, the during the ending scene: 

 the grandfather in the present reveals to the kid that he remembers everything that happened in the past.  At first it seems like they're still poor (and maybe losing the farm?) but the grandfather takes the kid to a hospital that is named for him, revealing that he followed the kids advice to invest in Japanese stocks prior to Black Tuesday.  

That's all I remember about the film.  Anyone know what movie this is?

Found it, thanks to the memory of my partner, who apparently watched it many more times than I did: Split Infinity . It wasn't a major movie, which is why I struggled to find it.
The plot follows the story of a young girl (14 years old) in the 1990s who's struggling with the simple life her family leads.  One night, while hiding in the family's barn, she falls and hits her head.  When she wakes up she finds herself in the body of her grandfather's younger sister (for whom she is named) in 1929 -- several weeks prior to the stock market crash.  Her grandfather is getting ready to sell the family farm in order to invest in the market.  
She spends the film trying to convince him she's really from the future (while getting used to life in the 1920s) and trying to prevent him from selling the farm.  

 In the end she fails to convince him not to sell the farm, and wakes up in the present day thinking the whole thing was a dream. But he reveals it wasn't a dream and that he followed her advice to invest in blue chip stocks after World War II and becomes wealthy.  He reveals this by showing her the children's hospital the construction of which he financed.


Daniel - you can 'self accept' this correct answer
